# Karma with Chrome - Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords

Tags: angular, karma-runner, selenium-chromedriver

I get the following error when Karma launches Chrome.
Also, this only happens on Windows; works fine on Linux.

`[4804:10108:0921/102208.538:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords`

Chrome installed - Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Relevant packages -
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.1",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/common": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/core": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
"@angular/forms": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/http": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/router": "~4.4.1",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0"

chromedriver_2.32.zip
selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar

Example test case -

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { provideRoutes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { ApiService } from './shared';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { MenuModule } from './menu/menu.module';
import { SecurityModule } from '@savantly/ngx-security';

describe('App', () => {
  // provide our implementations or mocks to the dependency injector
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, MenuModule, SecurityModule, MaterialModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [ApiService, provideRoutes([])]
    });
  });

  it('should have an url', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(true);
  });

});
```